# How to maintain the dot in the journal field of a bib item

Tags: bibtex, journal

I have an example bib entry:

```
@article{bib_1, 
 title={article1}, 
 journal={arXiv:15xx.01678 [cs.SE]}, 
 author={xxx.}, 
 year={2015}, 
 month={Jan}}
```

When it compiles, the output of the journal is:

```
arXiv:15xx01678 [csSE]
```

How can I avoid the dot from being removed?

=Update===

Here is a mini example showing the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45318932/example.zip

I am using the plos2009.bst - the reference style of PloS.

If you can not download the example, here are the content of the files in the example:

example.tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\bibliographystyle{plos2009}


\begin{document}

Some text, \cite{LeoTask_2015}.

\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

plos2009.bst:

http://www.plosone.org/static/plos2009.bst

references.bib:

```
@article{LeoTask_2015, 
 title={LeoTask: a fast, flexible and reliable framework for computational research}, 
 url={http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01678},
 journal={arXiv:1501.01678 [cs.SE]},
 author={xxxx}, 
 year={2015}, 
 month={Jan}
}
```

Comment: Please, make a minimal example of a complete document showing the issue.

Comment: Too much information missing, e.g. with what system and styles do you compile your bibliography (as egreg said, provide a minimal example that can be compiled and shows the problem). Also: Strictly speaking the Journal Field is supposed to hold the journal name, not the arXiv ID.

Comment: A full MWE would be really helpful to investigate further... Anyway, `biblatex` has dedicated fields to deal with arXiv ids and the like: it would be `eprint = {15xx.01678},
eprinttype = {arxiv},
eprintclass = {cs.SE},` in your example. (Do you actually use `biblatex`?)

Comment: @egreg. I updated the question with a mini example. I tried eprint, eprinttype, eprintclass, etc but they are not supported by the style of  plos2009.bst.

Comment: @Leo Again, the simple reason is that PLOS uses an abbreviation scheme that deletes the dots in journal name abbreviations. And again, if you want to use the PLOS style in a meaningful way, the arXiv is NOT what should go into the Journal Field. This field is reserved for the NAME of the journal in which the article was published. And for that matter, the arXiv ID is already included in the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reasons known only to the Public Library of Science (PLoS), the journal names are stripped of periods, so “J. Amer. Math. Soc.” would become “J Amer Math Soc”, which is very dubious.

The solution is *not* to use the `@article` type for something published on arXiv, because arXiv is not a journal.

### File `example.tex`

```
% Template for PLoS
% Version 3.0 December 2014
%
% To compile to pdf, run:
% latex plos.template
% bibtex plos.template
% latex plos.template
% latex plos.template
% dvipdf plos.template
%

\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{url}

\bibliographystyle{plos2009}


\begin{document}

Some text, \cite{LeoTask_2015}.

\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

### File `references.bib`

```
@misc{LeoTask_2015,
 title={{LeoTask}: a fast, flexible and reliable framework for computational research},
 url={http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01678},
 howpublished={arXiv:1501.01678 [cs.SE]},
 author={xxxx},
 year={2015},
 month={Jan}
}
```

Note the braces around `LeoTask` in the title in order to avoid lowercase.

### Output

[image]

Comment: +1 for "The solution is *not* to use the `@article` type for something published on arXiv, because arXiv is not a journal." :-) [You beat me to the answer by a couple of minutes...]

Comment: @egreg Journal names without dots is standard in MEDLINE (PubMed's large literature database). Relatively common (obviously) in medicine, and as you see also in some natural sciences journals. It's by far not the weirdest convention I have been coming across.